# How to get my list of rows from database to show while using Zend-Paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I'm fairly new to the world of Zend-Framework, and have taken over a site that is in zend-framework. There is a bug on one of the pages right now and I can not figure it out. I think it has something to do with Zend Paginator, but not sure.

This is the code in the controller for the section I am having a problem with:

```
$currentPage = $this->_getParam('page');
$numWebsitesFullOnline = $websites->getWebsitesFullOnline();

$select = $websites->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from(array('w' => 'websites'), array('id', 'online', 'kw_adjective', 'kw_name', 'kw_location', 'url', 'email', 'address', 'ftp_server', 'ftp_username', 'ftp_password', 'ftp_folder', 'phone_number', 'indexed', 'youtube_position', 'twitter_user', 'facebook_id', 'video_made', 'image1_id', 'image2_id', 'image3_id', 'bg_color', 'dark_color', 'light_color', 'links_color', 'text_color', 'google_account', 'ganalytics', 'gmaps_status', 'google_position', 'gmap_position', 'hp1', 'hp2', 'hp3', 'hp4', 'hp5', 'hp6', 'hp7', 'hp8', 'hp9', 'hp10', 'about1_id', 'about2_id', 'about3_id', 'tip1_id', 'tip2_id', 'tip3_id', 'contact_texts_id', 'quote_texts_id', 'demographics_id'))
    ->join(array('d' => 'demographics'), 'w.demographics_id = d.id', array('total_population'))
    ->order(array('total_population DESC', 'kw_location'));
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(50);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($currentPage);
$paginator->setPageRange(($paginator->getTotalItemCount() / 50) + 1);
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;

$numWebsitesOnline = $websites->getWebsitesOnline();
```

On the php page I have this code to call the websites that are in the database to a list:

```
<p class="red">
Websites online: <?php echo $this->numOnline; ?>
</p>

<?php print_r(count($this->paginator)); ?>

<?php if(count($this->paginator)): ?>

<table class="table-list">
<?php foreach($this->paginator as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php if($this->userIsAllowedAction('websites', 'reload')): ?>
        <td class="center noborder w30">
            <img class="hidden" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() . '/images/loader.gif' ?>" alt="Loading..."/><a class="reload" title="refresh" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/utils/ui/refresh-website.php" rel="<?php echo urlencode('http://' . $item['url'] . '/install.php'); ?>,<?php echo urlencode($item['ftp_server']); ?>,<?php echo $item['ftp_username']; ?>,<?php echo $item['ftp_password']; ?>,<?php echo $item['ftp_folder']; ?>,<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>,<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/icon-refresh.png" alt="Refresh"/></a>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="center noborder w30">
            <?php if($this->userIsAllowedAction('websites', 'edit')): ?><a title="Edit" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'websites', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $item['id'])); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/icon-edit.png" alt="Edit"/></a><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center noborder w30">
            <?php if($this->userIsAllowedAction('websites', 'remove')): ?><a title="Remove" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'websites', 'action' => 'remove', 'id' => $item['id'])); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/icon-delete.png" alt="Remove"/></a><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if($item['online']): ?>
                <span class="hidden"><?php echo trim($this->escape($item['kw_adjective'] . $item['kw_name'])); ?></span><a class="goto-website" href="http://<?php echo $item['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->escape($item['kw_location']); ?></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escape($item['kw_location']); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center population">
            <?php if($item['total_population'] >= 0) echo $item['total_population']; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['url'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['email'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['demographics_id']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['hp1'] && $item['hp2'] && $item['hp3'] && $item['hp4'] && $item['hp5'] && $item['hp6'] && $item['hp7'] && $item['hp8'] && $item['hp9'] && $item['hp10'] && $item['about1_id'] && $item['about2_id'] && $item['about3_id'] && $item['tip1_id'] && $item['tip2_id'] && $item['tip3_id'] && $item['contact_texts_id'] && $item['quote_texts_id']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $this->baseUrl() . Zend_Registry::get('assets_base_path') . '/' . $item['id'] . '/header.jpg')): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php
                if(($item['bg_color'] != '' && $item['bg_color'] != 'e6e6e6')
                || ($item['dark_color'] != '' && $item['dark_color'] != '003e75')
                || ($item['light_color'] != '' && $item['light_color'] != '3073ad')
                || ($item['links_color'] != '' && $item['links_color'] != '255593')
                || ($item['text_color'] != '' && $item['text_color'] != '4f4f4f')):
            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['image1_id'] && $item['image2_id'] && $item['image3_id']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['twitter_user'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['facebook_id'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['phone_number'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['google_account']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['video_made']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['youtube_position']) { echo $item['youtube_position']; }; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['address'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['gmaps_status'] == 1): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/icon-gmapspending.png" alt="Pending"/><?php elseif($item['gmaps_status'] == 2): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if(!empty($item['ganalytics'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark.png" alt="DONE"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['online']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark_red.png" alt="Online!"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['indexed']): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/check_mark_red.png" alt="Online!"/><?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['gmap_position']) { echo $item['gmap_position']; }; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php if($item['google_position']) { echo $item['google_position']; }; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The print_r(count($this->paginator)); line is returning "0", and the $this->numOnline; line is returning 1. So it sees that there is one row in the websites table of the database, but it is not returning anything to page and listing out the rows in the websites table. Not sure if this is the paginator that is causing this cause it is returning 0 or something else I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about that, but try to use joinLeft instead of join, maybe it's just the relation between websites table and demographics table who is making this result.